# Strange outcome from running Importpfx.exe to import certificates

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am writing a Powershell script to automate the setting up of a Windows 2008 R2 server and one thing that is required is the importing of several certificates into different stores. After doing some research on how best to achieve this, I found that Importpfx.exe was the best choice for what I am aiming to do, which is import one .pfx file into the Trusted People store  and another .pfx file into the Personal store, both for the Computer account. I then also need to Manage Private keys on the certificate imported into the Personal store once it has been imported.

At first, I thought that Importpfx.exe was doing this correctly, but after researching on how to manage the private keys via Powershell, I learned that this can be done my editing the acl for the file that corresponds to the imported certificate which should be found here "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys". This is where I started to notice that something wasn't quite right with the imported certificate. After searching this folder for a new file after importing the certificates, I noticed that no new files had been added to this folder.

I searched the entire C drive for all files sorted by date modified and found that new files had been added to this folder "C:\Users\'user'\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-2545654756-3424728124-1046164030-4917" instead of the expected folder. Whilst I was able to manually manage private keys for the certificate via the certificate store (as I was user who imported it), no other users were able to log onto the machine and manage the private keys, getting the error message "Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption" (which would make sense given the folder that the corresponding file exists in).

I use a function to get the thumbprint of the certificates before trying to import the .pfx file. The code I have used to run is:

```
function GetCertificateThumbprint ( [string]$certPreFix, [string]$certPassword, [string]$certFolder, [string]$domain, [bool]$addIfNotFound, [hashtable]$return)

$storePath = "cert:\LocalMachine"
$storeDir = "My"
$storeName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My
if($certPreFix -eq "XXX")
{
    $storeDir = "TrustedPeople"
    $storeName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::TrustedPeople
}
$storePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($storePath, $storeDir)
#Build the certificate file name and get the file
$certFileName = $certPreFix + "." + $domainName + ".*"
$certFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $certFolder -Include $certFileName -Recurse
if ($certFile)
{
#   The certificate file exists so get the thumbprint   
    $Certificate = New-Object system.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFile, $certPassword)
    $certThumbprint = $Certificate.Thumbprint
    if($addIfNotFound)
    {
#       Check for the certificate's thumbprint in store and add if it does not exist already    
        if(-not(Get-ChildItem $storePath | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $certThumbprint}))
        {
            Set-Location "$Env:windir\Tools"
            .\importpfx.exe -f $certFile -p $certPassword -t MACHINE -s $storeDir
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see if I have done anything wrong? Has anyone come across this issue and got around it somehow? This is causing me issues as I cannot automate the Manage Private keys task properly!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to the same problem. You must specify the *MachineKeySet* [X509KeyStorageFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags.aspx) when creating the certificate object:

```
New-Object system.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFile, $certPassword, "PersistKeySet,MachineKeySet")
```

Hopefully that helps someone.